# Changing the password of a user through PHPmyadmin

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

So I have an account on my web application, when I try to change the password it redirects me to the error page and I can't figure out why. I want to change the password to one of the accounts.

`dc7f3da29862d3d5b3d3cd32356659ea7e85ed032b9c5144f5`

The password is stored as this (the password is only `password` so I don't mind this being here)

```
{
                            $result = $this->User->editUser($id,$username, $email, $name, $surname, $phone, $hash);
                            if ($result == true)
                            {
                                $this->set('has_message',true);
                                $this->set('css_name','success');
                                $this->set('errors',"<p>User successfully updated.</p>");
                                $profile = $this->User->getUserbyid($id);
                                $this->set('profile',$profile);
                                $this->User->closeConnection();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $this->User->closeConnection();
                                $this->set('has_message',true);
                                $this->set('css_name','error');
                                $this->set('errors',"<p>Something went wrong please try again.</p>");
                            }
                        }
```

This is the code for editing a user account, I am new to PHP so please tell me if there is any more code you need...I am stuck trying to fix this error....and if possible I would just change the password in PHPMyAdmin instead as I don't mind if users cannot change their password.

Hash methods:

```
$salt = $this->create_salt_password($username);
                $hash = $salt . $password;
                for ( $i = 0; $i < 100000; $i ++ ) 
                {
                    $hash = hash('sha256', $hash);
                }
                $hash = $salt . $hash;
```

And in config.php the salt

```
define('AUTH_SALT','wcRwGxDzULe?s3J%R^W@9)r}xfXpESul5hC,z^ze.oz*1E|ys,Bk,:Q/z_I&M9..');
```

and

```
public function create_salt_password($username)
        {
        /** Creates a hash value for the password using 
            a prefixed random unique identifier value with a static characters and the username
        */
            $salt = hash('sha256', uniqid(mt_rand(), true) .AUTH_SALT .strtolower($username));
            return $salt;
        }
```

Login script:

```
$salt = substr($results->password, 0, 64);
                $password = $salt . $password;
                for ( $i = 0; $i < 100000; $i ++ ) 
                {
                    $password = hash('sha256', $password);
                }
```

Comment: `I am stuck trying to fix this error` -- you haven't told us what error you're getting.

Comment: `100000` sha256 hash iterations, yet the same salt for every user.

Comment: @Paulpro I don't follow sorry?

Comment: @germainelol It looks like you're aiming for extremely secure passwords, but if two users of your application pick the same password, they will have the same password hash. It's better to generate a random salt for every user so that users with the same password have the same chance of having the same hash as each other as two user's with different passwords. Imagine if 1000 users all pick "password" as their password. The way you have it set-up now there will be 1000 corresponding hashes in the database.

Comment: It's okay for what I want it to do, I'm having a very hard time generating the hash so that i can change the password on phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change your password through `phpmyadmin`, first find out which hashing method is used to store the password in the database (md5, sha1). Then generate the password using online hash tools like [sha1-online.com](http://sha1-online.com) or just get the hashed password using php script and save it to your database.

Comment: Ive updated my answer with the methods for saving a new user, could you explain how to work this out? I've tried using the sha1-online.com website that you linked but had no luck generating the same string as I posted above

Comment: I noticed that the string you posted has a length of 50 characters but sha1 has a length of 40 characters. The framework you are using may be using external logic to hash the password to 50 characters. You need to find the function from within your framework that is used to hash the password. Which framework are you using? The list of different hash sizes can be found at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php#111734

Comment: I added the external function to the post

Comment: And what is the username that is being passed to `create_salt_password($username)`?

Comment: sweetest_viv is username

Comment: creating the salt with the random unique id!! Wondering how the script is checking the password during login? Can you check that script? Seriously stucked :D

Comment: I added it to the post, I think it is similar to the other code to check it